# React Native - Splash Screen Changing Error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, splash-screen

Hi I used This Article to Changing my Splash Screen for android via react native But I Got This Error:
[Article link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

```
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL  
Total time: 1 mins 43.179 secs
Running C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 5203fc0e586a3409 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 5203fc0e586a3409 (C:\Users\Saeed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 5203fc0e586a3409 shell am start -n com.mohajerkade/.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.mohajerkade/.MainActivity VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.mohajerkade/com.mohajerkade.MainActivity} does not exist.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

First I have Splash Screen for 3 secend and After that** I got a red Screen  `Error calling AppRegistry.runApplication` in my mobile** and Can't See React Native `Hello World`

This is my MainActivity.java :

```
package com.mohajerkade;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "Mohajerkade";
    }
}
```

and This is SplashActivity.java  :

```
    package com.mohajerkade;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

I Used This Toturial But I Don't Know How Should I See Splash Screen In application loading and after that react native `Hello World`.

Comment: start the server using react-native start and then press run button from android studio.

Comment: I'm using my phone to run and debug app and I don't have simulator, today when I started, It said, `unfortunately. myAppName has stopped` .  my codes are default of react native.

Comment: I have gone through your code and it seems you are using native code rather than react native code for splash screen. Is there any reason for such kind of approach? react native provide easy to handle components to display splash screen in iOS as well as android. But in xcode(iOS) you can directly put splashscreen according to the device size. Feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start it fresh, Lets go step by step.

- delete previous app from your phone
- start the server (`react-native start`)
- press run button from your android studio
- after that from your app open the developer's menu
- set your localhost(IP address:8081) by going to the option Debug server host for
  device.
- Reload and you are good to go.

Note:

> If the phone is connected through USB then connect your system and
>   phone 
>         with same wifi, else run adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Cheers :)

Comment: every day I used This Command `react-native run-android` without android Studio,But Now I opened my React Native Project with Android Studio But I Got `A problem occurred configuration project 'app'.  The SDK Build Tools revision23.0.1 is too low , Minimum required is 25.0.0` , But In React native tutorial said: make sure that Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.1 is selected, and Run Button in Android Studio  is disabled,

Comment: There might be an option coming with the error to install the build tools so simply install that build tool version from there.